# RuntimeException on populating Action bar to sub activities

Tags: java, android

Iam new to android/coding/Java, please go easy on me if mistakes

Iam trying to reproduce same Action bar for the sub activities of my Main Activity (**LoginActivity**)
 here is my LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        actionBar = getActionBar();// ActionBar Customisations
                actionBar.setTitle("Klok Innovations");
                actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.collection_report);
                actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
                actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

The app crashes when i open it ... Here is the **logcat**

```
07-04 17:24:15.005 7636-7636/online.klok.mobpos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: online.klok.mobpos, PID: 7636
  Theme: themes:{}
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{online.klok.mobpos/online.klok.mobpos.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
      at online.klok.mobpos.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:28)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Also how can I create bar at the bottom of the screen and appear in all my sub activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is why because your actionbar getting null pointer exeption:

try like this

```
assert actionbar != null;
if(actionbar != null){
   **write your code here**
}
```

now its never be null..

2. you are using appCompateActivity so use getSupportActionBar.  add this lines in your every subActivity in onCreate method.

   ```
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
      // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title Here");
   ```

that commented line is for back button at upper left corner.. if you want it then uncomment it. and write some line in manifest to do some back button action.

```
<activity android:name=".yourSubActivityName">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".whichActivityYouWantToGo" />
</activity>
```

3. if you are in mainActivity and want to exit app using dialog.. here is the code.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
       builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
               .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               dialog.dismiss();
                               finish();
                           }
                       })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });
       // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
       builder.create();
       builder.show();
   }
   ```

Comment: The thing is i want to populate it to all my Sub activities ... is it possible without creating it on every activity

Comment: what do you mean by populating.?

Comment: I want to display the action bar on my sub activities ... without setting views on each of them

Comment: ok.. first tell me what is your latest api that you testing your app.. otherwise show me your gradle so i can understand everything, after that i will modify my answer

Comment: My build.gradle [link](http://hastebin.com/yubeninora.vbs) 

what if i want to exit App if pressed back button ie when iam on parent activity with an Alert box for exit ing

Comment: first of all change your dependency version 23.4.0 to 23.3.0 because your using buildToolVersion is 23.0.3 so.

Comment: i hope my updated answer solve all your question..

Comment: thanks @Sagar Chavada

Comment: still have a few more questions ... would you mind if we take this to a better chat client  something like hangouts or ....? If you agree can i have your mail id ?

............... PS : less than 15 rep , they wouldn't allow me to up-vote it

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
getSupportActionBar();
```

instead of

```
getActionBar();
```

Comment: well both of them throws NullPointerException
, If Its just an activity then 


`getSupportActionBar();`


wouldn't work

Comment: try getDelegate().getSupportActionBar();